# Secure Login to a api with username and password

Tags: ruby, web-services, security, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a simple api system in ruby to use with my app. For my website itself, I'll use a secure login form, but I'd like to have a api for the desktop app. I'd like to keep it simple, I'd prefer not to need to go with a system like OAuth 2. First, I don't want to force the app to login via a login website or for the user to have to provide a api key. I'd prefer to only to need a users email and password to login, like what dropbox does for their client login in the desktop. Would Basic Authentication be secure in this situation, on the provision that my app caches the password securely? Is their any other system I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic auth is secure if (and only if) you use it via HTTPS.  The same applies to forms based authentication or digest.

As for caching the password, if you mean client side, that's questionable from a security perspective but understandable for user experience.  If you're talking server side, that's a terrible idea.  Never store a user's password.

Only ever store a hashed password (PBKDF2, bcrypt, etc.).